# Vitualization in HP-UX

Tags: windows-server-2003, virtualization, virtualbox, hp-ux

I have a powerful server with hp-ux.  I  received a request to install new software (that only runs under windows server).  I have no available windows servers at this moments, but I have lots of resources available in the HP-UX server.

My question is: Is possible virtualize a windows server 2003 in an HP-UX Server?  Using, for example virtualbox, that is free, but i don´t know if supports HP-UX.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doing some quick Googling, it appears that under nPartitions on Itanium, you can run Windows, presumably the IA64 architecture. That's not virtualization in the sense of VMware, but if your hardware is Itanium, look into that.

Idle wondering - how do IT and the business manage to get themselves into a box like this? The business buys software without even bothering to find out if the capacity is there? If this request is only for fact-finding, and the business didn't already buy the software, then my apologies, that's not the situation you're in.

Comment: Thanks, the software will be purchased, And if is imposible virtualize in HP-uX(that is my question), then a new windows server will be purchased too.

Comment: As I said, the answer to your question is "yes" if you're running on Itanium and you can buy and run Windows 2003 or 2008 IA64, and if your application will run on Windows 2003 or 2008 IA64. So, what is your HP hardware?

Comment: You marked this as the answer, which is great - but I'm still curious. Is your HPUX machine Itanium-based, and will your software run on Windows IA64?

Comment: uhmmm, no my machine is not itanium-based.. then the only solution(because there is not a virtualization solution in the sense of VMWARE) is purchase a windows server, for this software and possible other software too. Thanks for your time

Answer (score 1):

You could use [HPVM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HP_Integrity_Virtual_Machines). It can actually run Windows, but it won't run your software unless it's compiled for Windows on IA64.

Answer (score 0):

As said before, you could virtualize the IA64 port of Windows 2003 or 2008 if you run Itanium hardware.  I assume since you said it's not Itanium, it must be PA-RISC.  Is that true?

If so, I'd be curious to know how you have "a powerful server with hp-ux"?  PA-RISC has been obsolete for a long time.